# How to write LinkedList<Pair<Long, Pair<String, String>>> to TextFile, using JavaSpark

Tags: java, apache-spark, parsing

i`m newbie in Spark and I just can’t figure out how to write the code below into a text or object file using Spark for Java.
I have a List in which I write data from a file that has been processed

```
List<Pair<Long, Pair<String, String>>> parsedLog = new List<Pair<Long, Pair<String, String>>>();
```

Parsing text file

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            String parsedLine = line.trim();
            if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {

                if (!isOperatorHelpToken) {
                    emptyLinesCount = 0;
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(": *");
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(parsedLine);
                    if (matcher.find()) {
                        String parsedName = parsedLine.substring(0, matcher.start());
                        String parsedValue = parsedLine.substring(matcher.end());

                        propertyValue = parsedValue;
                        propertyName = parsedName;

                            for (int i = 0; i < purge.length; ++i)
                            {
                                propertyName = propertyName.replace(purge[i], "");
                                propertyValue = propertyValue.replace(purge[i], "");

                            }
```

And then i add it to List

```
if (line.equals(operatorHelpEndMark)) {
                        propertyValue = String.join("\30", operatorHelpText);
                        parsedLog.add(new Pair<Long, Pair<String, String>>
                                (alertCounter, new Pair<String, String>(propertyName, propertyValue)));
```

I tried to write to a file as follows

```
  JavaPairRDD<Long, Pair<String, String>> javaPairRDD =
                   (JavaPairRDD<Long, Pair<String, String>>)
                           sparkContext.parallelizePairs(parsedLog);

            JavaPairRDD<Long, String> javaPairRDDForSaveToFile = javaPairRDD.mapValues(
                    (Function) stringStringTuple2 -> stringStringTuple2.toString()
            );
            javaPairRDDForSaveToFile.coalesce(2).saveAsTextFile("home/test/1.csv");
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: instead of writing to a file, a folder is created with the name "_temporary" and files of this type ".part-00000.crc"

Comment: It might not have been finished writing it yet

Comment: execution ends with "Process finished with exit code 0"